# How to sum up records from starting month to current per month

Tags: mysql, sql

I've searched for this topic but all I got was questions about grouping results by month. I need to retrieve rows grouped by month with summed up cost from start date to this whole month

Here is an example table

```
   Date     |  Val
----------- | -----
2017-01-20  | 10  
----------- | -----
2017-02-15  | 5  
----------- | -----
2017-02-24  | 15  
----------- | -----
2017-03-14  | 20
```

I need to get following output (date format is not the case):

```
2017-01-20 | 10
2017-02-24 | 30
2017-03-14 | 50
```

When I run

```
SELECT SUM(`val`) as `sum`, DATE(`date`) as `date` FROM table
AND `date` BETWEEN :startDate 
AND :endDate GROUP BY year(`date`), month(`date`)
```

I got sum per month of course.

Nothing comes to my mind how to put in nicely in one query to achieve my desired effect, probably W will need to do some nested queries but maybe You know some better solution.

Comment: In SQL Server I would use window functions to get a running total, but I don't know if MySQL supports window functions, or how the syntax would differ if it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work (untestet). You could also solve this by using subqueries, but i guess that would be more costly. In case you want to sort the result by the total value the subquery variant might be faster.

```
SET @total:=0;
SELECT
   (@total := @total + q.sum) AS total, q.date
FROM
   (SELECT SUM(`val`) as `sum`, DATE(`date`) as `date` FROM table
AND `date` BETWEEN :startDate 
AND :endDate GROUP BY year(`date`), month(`date`)) AS q
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use DATE_FORMAT function to both, format your query and group by.

**[DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)(date,format)**

> Formats the date value according to the format string.

```
SELECT Date, @total := @total + val as total
FROM 
    (select @total := 0) x,
    (select Sum(Val) as Val, DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%m-%Y') as Date
     FROM st where Date >= '2017-01-01' and Date <= '2017-12-31'
     GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%m-%Y')) y
;

+---------+-------+
| Date    | total |
+---------+-------+
| 01-2017 | 10    |
+---------+-------+
| 02-2017 | 30    |
+---------+-------+
| 03-2017 | 50    |
+---------+-------+
```

Can check it here: http://rextester.com/FOQO81166

Comment: He doesn't want a sum-per-month, he wants a running total.

Comment: Date format is not the big deal, main problem was summing value

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

I use yearmonth as an integer (the year of the date multiplied by 100 plus the month of the date) . If you want to re-format, your call, but integers are always a bit faster.

It's the complete scenario, including input data.

```
CREATE TABLE tab (
  dt DATE
, qty INT
);

INSERT INTO tab(dt,qty) VALUES( '2017-01-20',10);
INSERT INTO tab(dt,qty) VALUES( '2017-02-15', 5); 
INSERT INTO tab(dt,qty) VALUES( '2017-02-24',15); 
INSERT INTO tab(dt,qty) VALUES( '2017-03-14',20);

SELECT
  yearmonths.yearmonth
, SUM(by_month.month_qty) AS running_qty
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT
  YEAR(dt) * 100 + MONTH(dt) AS yearmonth
FROM tab
) yearmonths
INNER JOIN (
SELECT
  YEAR(dt) * 100 + MONTH(dt) AS yearmonth
, SUM(qty)                 AS month_qty
FROM tab
GROUP BY YEAR(dt) * 100 + MONTH(dt) 
) by_month
ON yearmonths.yearmonth >= by_month.yearmonth
GROUP BY yearmonths.yearmonth
ORDER BY 1;
;


yearmonth|running_qty
  201,701|       10.0
  201,702|       30.0
  201,703|       50.0
select succeeded; 3 rows fetched
```

Need explanations?

My solution has the advantage over the others that it will be re-usable without change when you move it to a more modern database - and you can convert it to using analytic functions when you have time.

Marco the Sane